# OpenGL commands - sequential or parallel

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm reading [this document](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model)
and I have a question about this sentence:

> While OpenGL explicitly requires that commands are completed in order,
>   that does not mean that two (or more) commands cannot be concurrently
>   executing. As such, it is possible for shader invocations from one
>   command to be exeucting in tandem with shader invocations from other
>   commands.

Does this mean that, for example, when I issue two consecutive glDrawArrays calls it is possible that the second call is processed immediately before the first one has finished?

My first idea was that the OpenGL calls merely map to internal commands of the gpu and that the OpenGL call returns immediately without those commands completed, thus enabling the second OpenGL call to issue its own internal commands. The internal commands created by the OpenGL calls can then be parallelized.

Comment: Your question is merely restating *exactly* what the quoted text says as a question. So, are you merely asking if the quoted text is correct?

Answer (score 0):

What is says is, that the exact order in which the commands are executed and any concurrency is left to the judgement of the implementation with the only constraint being that the final result must look exactly as if all the commands would have been executed one after another in the very order they were called by the client program.

EDIT: Certain OpenGL calls cause an implicit or explicit synchronization. Reading back pixels for example or waiting for a synchronization event.

Comment: But there are functions (memory barriers etc.) that are needed to guarantee this in some situations. How can this be a standard requirement if there are so many exceptions that need to be fixed by the user?

Comment: @user5024425: Well I did mention explicit synchronisation. If out-of-order operation makes you feel uneasy, let me put extra fuel into that fire by telling you, that regular CPUs are just as out-of-order as well. The instructions in an applications binary are usually not executed in the same order as they appear in and only at points where data dependencies arise the program flow is synchronized. Note that I'm not talking about multithreading and SMP here, this is single thread out-of-order execution. Some architectures (Alpha) don't even try to hide that fact.

Comment: @user5024425: As far as "fixing" goes. There's not much to fix as long as the outcome is correct. The OpenGL specification guarantees you, that if you draw a quad and then a line over each other into a texture using a FBO and then source that texture for another draw, thing will seem to have happened in that order. Memory barriers and fences exist in OpenGL for the same reason they exist in multiprocessor architectures: To synchronize program flows where the data dependency can not be unambiguously inferred.